# Best way to send a file back to a user from an API with PHP

Tags: php, css, api

This is a bit tricky to explain, i'm making an API where i take a file from a user via a cURL command. I then process this file and send it back to them. The file is going to be a CSS file.

I'm asking what's the best method for this whole process, do i ask them to send the contents in a variable as a string and then return it to them in a string. Or can the user send me the complete file that i then read into a variable and process and somehow send it back to them as a file?

This service is likely to be the last step in their process before they deploy their site to a live server, so what is the best method for them to receive the file? Is it best to get them to reference my site in their  tags, ie. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://myApi.com/http://usersSite.com/site/style.css" />` I can then parse said file and just return the processed file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/css');
$data=file_get_contents($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

// process $data here

echo $data;
?>
```

and invoke it by using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://myApi.com/?http://usersSite.com/site/style.css" />
```

Comment: As a user, would you rely on a an external site to essentially host your CSS for your site? Is this the best way?

Comment: No i personally wouldn't. I would offer both options, direct including and downloading, to your users and let them choose.

Comment: Also i'd add a third option, where the user can either paste the css into a textfield or upload a css file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to zip this file and send complete file in zip.